# If X function was not successful do Y

Tags: php

I need to know if a function I have just run was not successful. Below is the function in question and how it executes.

I know how I can do this by setting a variable from within the function and checking if it exists but, not sure that's the best practice.

```
//Update users function
function update($db, $fn, $ln, $email, $offers, $vlue, $responce)
{
    $stmt = $db->prepare("insert into kkt (fName_765, lName_765, email_765, signup_765, kkt_resp_765, stamp_765) values (:fname, :lname, :email, :signup, NOW())");

    $parameters = array(
        ':fname' => $fn,
        ':lname' => $ln,
        ':email' => $email,
        ':signup' => $offers);

    $stmt->execute($parameters);
    print $db->lastInsertId(); //show ID
    return true;
}


//Test Attributes
$fn = 'test';
$ln = 'test';
$email = 'tesst@test,com';
$offers = '1';

try {
    update($db, $fn, $ln, $email, $offers);
}
catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo "no update there is a slight problem " . $e->getMessage();
}
```

I will use the try catch to notify myself via email if it was not successful, but should I put the code I am going to show the user in here or is it best to write something else to keep it neater?

Thanks for all your comments - the final code is now over at CR: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/21481/pdo-connection-prep-and-execute-in-there-own-functions

Comment: Does this work, and you're just after best practice advice? Try-catch is a good way to do this, though as it stands you don't need to return true, since you don't use it. If `update()` is used in various places, I'd be inclined to put the try/catch inside the function, and return `true` if everything was okay, and a string message if there was a problem. You can then do `if ($result !== true)` to test if an error occurred.

Comment: see below about being advised to put this not in the function, but reading this it makes sense to have this back in the function. thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In PHP you can deal with it in three different ways and they will all be considered good because PHP itself use them all (which is indeed confusing as it seems). You could return false on error (and deal with its return result):

```
function update($db, $fn, $ln, $email, $offers, $vlue, $responce) {
    try {
        ...
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

You could trigger an error (and notify yourself via email in the error handler):

```
function update($db, $fn, $ln, $email, $offers, $vlue, $responce) {
    try {
        ...
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        trigger_error("...", E_USER_WARNING);
    }
}
```

or you could throw your own exception (and send an email when catching it):

```
function update($db, $fn, $ln, $email, $offers, $vlue, $responce) {
    try {
        ...
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        throw new Exception("...");
    }
}
```

It doesn't really matter. But what is usually suggested is that:

- you use Exceptions when you are managing to recover somehow the error or if it is an error that shouldn't stop the entire program
- you use bool return values only when they are really required (for `is_*` type of functions) and not for errors
- you use `trigger_error` when you want to stop the execution of the entire program

Comment: thank you i may just add this back into the function, help appricated

Answer (score 2):

You can use `if(function())` to check if function was executed successfully or not. it returns Boolean flag in `true` or `false`.

```
if(update("test","test","test@test,com",1))
{ 
   //successful 
}
else
{ 
   //callfunction2() 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

i think you can use try-catch in function:

```
function update($db, $fn, $ln, $email, $offers, $vlue, $responce)
{
    $stmt = $db->prepare("insert into kkt (fName_765, lName_765, email_765, signup_765, kkt_resp_765, stamp_765) values (:fname, :lname, :email, :signup, NOW())");

    $parameters = array(
        ':fname' => $fn,
        ':lname' => $ln,
        ':email' => $email,
        ':signup' => $offers);

    try {
       $stmt->execute($parameters);
       print $db->lastInsertId(); //show ID
       return true;
    } catch(Exception $ex) {
       //log, or pirint error message
       //or return 0
       return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: i did have the try and catch in the function and was advised it would be best to have this out of the function.  http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/21481/pdo-connection-prep-and-execute-in-there-own-functions

Answer (score 1):

```
try {
    $result=update($db, $fn, $ln, $email, $offers);
    if(!$result)
        throw new Exception("Query not succesful!");
}
catch (PDOException $e) {
    mail("what","ever","you","want");
    echo "no update there is a slight problem " . $e->getMessage();
}
```